# Matlab anonymous function with array inputs

Tags: arrays, matlab, anonymous-function, dimensions

I have an anonymous function:

```
a = [1, 2];
b = [1, 1; 3, 2];
c = [4, 2];
ff = @(x) (exp(a .* x) .* c) * b;
```

The problem is that, when I have an array, say `x = [1,2,3,4]` , Matlab thinks that I'm using the array and multiplying that in the exponential, and not each element.
The error is

> Error using  .* 
>   Matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in
>   @(x)(exp(a.*x).*c)*b

I just need something like  `c1 * exp(a1 *x) * b11 + c2 * exp(a2 * x) * b21 + ...`

I can use a `for` loop if I want to evaluate the function for each `x` element and it gives me the answer that I want, but I think there may be an easiest way, like when we can use simply `f(x)` and get an array with each element evaluated in the function. I tried using `arrayfun` but I get the same error. I want to skip `for` loops since they are slow for bigger matrices.

Comment: You surely mean `c1 * exp(a1 *x) * b11 + c2 * exp(a2 * x) * b21 + ...`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'll correct my question

Comment: Which size should your result be (for the given example values)?

Comment: For a particular `x` , a 1x2 array. If I use a Nx1 array, it should give a Nx2 array with each column for different `x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

```
results = arrayfun(ff, x ,  'UniformOutput', false);
results{:}
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, thank you. What does the `{:}` do? Since with the first command I get something like `[1x2 double]`

Comment: @DavidWinchester `arrayfun` returns a cell. `results{:}` will just output the results.

Comment: Can I store the results in a new array? Doing `results = results{:}` just gives me the first value

Comment: @DavidWinchester Yes, use `results = cell2mat(results.');` to get an Nx2 matrix

Comment: Oh, @LuisMendo you answered me before, thank you, it works :) . What's the `.'` for?

Comment: @DavidWinchester `.'` is matrix or array transposition. It turns the 1x4 array of 1x2-vectors into a 4x1 array of the same 1x2-vectors; and then `cellmat` puts that into matrix (4x2) form

Comment: Thanks, I got confused by the dot. Now I get it. It seems to work also without the `.`

Comment: @DavidWinchester Without the dot it also applies complex conjugation. Careful with that if you apply it for example to a matrix of complex numbers.

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks for pointing that out :) Indeed, I have imaginary values

Answer (score 1):

Use `arrayfun(ff,x,'UniformOutput',false)` to return the 4 cells corresponding to your four outputs.
I think it should be `c1 * exp(a1 *x) * b11 + c2 * exp(a2 * x) * b21 + ...` otherwise you need to transpose your `b` matrix before the multiplication.

Comment: Yes, someone pointed that out before, I corrected my question. Thanks.